# Parse js sdk, How do you query many to many in document DB?

Tags: parse-platform

In the Parse js guide it says:

> For example, a User may have many Posts that she might like. In this case, you can store the set of Posts that a User likes using relation. In order to add a Post to the “likes” list of the User, you can do:
>
> `var user = Parse.User.current();
>   var relation = user.relation("likes");
>   relation.add(post);
>   user.save();`

My use case is actually this exact setup.  We have Users and they can "like" 0-many Posts, so I set it up exactly as stated above.  My issue now is that for a given Post or set of Posts, I need to query how many users have liked each Post.  I'm having trouble figuring out how to query for that... Can someone help me out? I'm not sure if this is a limitation or if I just don't know enough to figure this out.  I've thought about storing a counter on the Post itself and using increment() and decrement() each time a User likes or unlikes a Post, but I'd rather not if I can get away with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can do this. One would be to also have a relation on each post for `likedBy` so when a user likes a post, you add that user to the post's `likedBy` relation as well as adding the post the user's `likes` relation.

Another solution is to create a new Parse class for `Like`. Whenever a User likes a post, you create a new `Like` with a pointer to the `Post` and the `User` who liked it. Then if you want to find the posts that a user likes, you can easily query that, or if you want to know which users like a post, that query is just as simple.

I personally use the second approach, but either will work

Comment: Gotcha, so the second option is the typical way you'd do a many to many in a relational database.  I guess I'm going to go with the first option though because I'd rather take the hit upfront on the update and not have to do an extra query later when I fetch the data.